# em C# Gostaria exibir Moeda no formato Metical moeda de Moçambique

Tags: c#

olá,
em C#,

Tenho meu campos exibindo no formato moeda BRL em Reais símbolo >R$12,00 gostaria de exibir no formato Metical símbolo 12.00MT.

alguém pode me ajudar nesse exibição?

terei que alterar o banco? tá utf-8

obrigado,

Comment: sem ver o código eu diria para usar o `string.Format` por exemplo

Comment: O  String.Format seria pra formatar como Real 'R$' e fiz assim pra exibir em Reais.  'txtValorTotal.Text = String.Format("{0:c2}", total); isso me retorna R$:12,00. E para exibir na Grid faço assim:                                                  
             grid.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Status";
            //formatar coluna  moeda
            grid.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2";                                                                     Como farei para exibir 12.00MT ou 1500.50mt? Grato pela atenção.

Comment: se aparece R$ é pq a cultura da máquina está em pt-BR, precisaria mudar, mas fui verificar e não há um code para Moçambique infelizmente: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.regioninfo.isocurrencysymbol?view=net-5.0  vai precisar fazer isso manual :(

Comment: muito obrigado, vou analisar o link,